# Перенос консольного приложения на C# в Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, .net

Есть консольное приложение, клиент-сервер. Написано на C#, а точнее - код из учебника. С шарпом не знаком слишком, разбираюсь для себя. Собственно, вопрос: каким образом можно связать класс самого приложения с формой, в котором доступны элементы GUI, с классом, реализующим функционал, чтобы из последнего были доступны элементы формы?

Comment: Для начала, на начинайте учить богомерзкие WinForms, когда уже давно все программируют модные пацаны на светлом лучезарном WPF.

Comment: В принципе, попробовать можно, хотя с WinForms хоть как-то имел дело, когда для универа на бейсике писал.

Comment: Вопрос снимаю, помогли пункты 2.7.2 и 3.1 отсюда: http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread110436.html

Comment: Так делать неправильно.